# how to install fly in linux

Tags: linux, concourse

I ma newbie to concourse. I am able to install fly cli in windows by just downloading the fly.exe and executing.how shall I install fly in linux server. I can login to linux server using putty or file zilla so I have downloaded fly version for linux and copied using file zilla however I am not able to install it.

Comment: What have you tried?  Btw, it took me 10 seconds of googling to find a **walk-through** on DigitalOcean, that may not match your needs 100% as it's for Ubuntu 16.04, but then you didn't specify the distro you're using ...

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-concourse-ci-on-ubuntu-16-04